# Can not update MySql by Hadoop, only insert

Tags: mysql, hadoop

I'm trying to use Hadoop to read data, process and then write back to MySql. However, it seems as if I can only do insertion. If I try to write back with the same primary key(it means update), there will be an error like "Duplicate XXX for primary key'. Has anyone solved this problem? And is it possible to update? Thanks very much!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using [Sqoop](http://incubator.apache.org/sqoop/) or using SQL statements in the Map/Reduce tasks? Looks like multiple reducers or a single reducer is writing data with the same primary key again and again. You have to redesign the map/reduce tasks or the database schema to get rid of the errors.

How is it known in the reducer, if an update or insert has to be done? Is the row with the same primary key checked in the database and then insert or update done?

The application design has to be known in detail to solve the problem.

Comment: when inserting into a database from a M/R job it is always useful to set reduce task to 1 if the key is primary key in the table to insert. If you don't care, do a "on duplicate key update/ignore"

Comment: @Thomas - How does it help to have one Reducer when `Reducer Key = Primary Key of Table`? I think, it shouldn't matter.

Comment: Because Hadoop takes care that the key is distinct/unique in the reduce step, preventing collisions in the database.

Comment: Thanks, Praveen and Thomas. I'm using DBOutputFormat. The problem is just as Thomas said, it's because there are really duplicate keys in the database. But I don't know how to set "on duplicate key update/ignore", because the insertion query is generated by DBOutputFormat. I'm trying, thanks!

Comment: @Thomas - I don't get it - pl explain in detail with an example - still I think 1 or N reducers doesn't matter. R1 would be getting K1, K2 and R2 would be getting K3 and K4 or else R1 would be getting K1, K2, K3 and K4. How does it matter?

Comment: @PraveenSripati - According to my experience, it happens when I tried to read something from a HDFS file and insert them to database twice. At first time, it's OK, but at second time, there will be the problem.